# What to understand by loaded by in performance result

Tags: performance-testing, web-performance, webpagetest

Lately i have seen high time to first byte for my sites.

Most of the time it is by javascript. A test at webpagetest.org usually shows like....

URL: http://example.com/
Loaded by: http://example.com/some-kind-of-javascript.js

When i remove that javascript then anothe javascript appears in that place.

What does loaded by exactly mean??

Check example test result....

https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190729_JY_cb028989b0f44671fba830c9eaca29d7/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it's Javascript that is the problem? It looks to me like it's the initial HTML that is causing the problem.

Time to First byte for a resource is the time take from after sending the request (e.g. `GET /`) until it receives the first byte back. It excludes the DNS lookup, TCP connection and SSL handshake time, so really is a measure of the time take to start receiving that resource. Note that the "first byte" time at the top of the waterfall is the [full end to end time, including DNS/TCP/SSL and any redirects](https://twitter.com/tunetheweb/status/1153932495617966080?s=20), but the TTFB for each resource this is split out more.

I don't know how your home page is created - I would guess it's not a static page so whatever is generating this (PHP?) is taking too long. Whether this is due to bad backend code, an under-resourced server, a slow database, or something else is impossible to say from the outside. I would suggest getting in touch with your hosting provider and/or reviewing your code and server.

Comment: My site is in php wordpress. But the same is happening with sites hosted at different place. Check this https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190729_TG_b742c2078c263f011b79d49d663cc6a9/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Comment: On that link TTFB is 548ms. On your first web page test link TTFB is 14587ms. That's a heck of a difference! So I don't agree the same is happening there.

Comment: Yes agreed (i tried default theme and ttfb is 700ms). But there is no way i can change theme. So i havve to find a way out to solve this 'loaded by' puzzle. @Barry Pollard